# How to handle data insertions in a foreign key reference relation

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to implement a flight booking system, and the use case is as follow:
A registered customer should be able to buy several tickets, not only for himself, and for each ticket the passenger info would be recorded.
In the database design, I have two tables -- a ticket table, and a purchase table. Tuples in the ticket table records only information with the flight and the passenger, and each ticket has a unique ticketID as primary key. Inside the purchase table, it has a foreign key reference to the ticket table, and has attributes that indicate which registered use this purchase record belongs to.
Now, suppose I have several tuples of passenger data sent to the server, the first thing I should do is to insert new tickets, and then I could perform insertion on the purchase table indicates the relation between each tickets and the person who bought the tickets. Notice that the new records in the purchase table would have ticket_ids which were just created by new tickets.
My confusion is: how do I implement this within one operation as a whole? ** In the purchase table, I would also give the tuples that are created by the same customer in the same transaction an ID, indicates that those tickets belongs to the same purchase records. ** Could I achieve this using a stored procedure? I feel like the passing of data is tricky, since I'm very new to stored procedure, etc.

Comment: I think you should look up `Transactions` so that you get all the updates or none of the updates :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you, I would definitely do.